# How do I access form input from HTML/thymeleaf to Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to make a html page called balance where user inputs an account number. What's the best way to retrieve the input value to the controller? I tried this and I don't know if this is the right way.

```
    @PostMapping("/balance")
    public  String balanceCheck(@RequestParam("aNum") Long num,@ModelAttribute Transactions user,Model model) {


     int deposits=0;
     int withdraw=0;
     int balance=0;
     long accountNum= user.getAccountNum();


     Iterable <Transactions>accountTrans=  transactRepository.findByAccountNum(user.getAccountNum());

     for (Transactions tran: accountTrans){

         if (tran.getAction().equals("D")){

             deposits+=tran.getAmmount();
         }

         else if (tran.getAction().equals("W")){

             withdraw+=tran.getAmmount();
         }
     }

     balance=deposits-withdraw;
     model.addAttribute("balance", balance);




       return "balance" ;
    }
```

And this is my html:

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/balance}"  method="post">

    <p> ACCOUNT #: <input type="number" name="aNum "/></p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you post your question, be sure to specifically include what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

To print the value on the page, you'll want:

```
<form action="#" th:object="${user}" th:action="@{/balance}" method="post">

   <p>ACCOUNT #: <input type="number" th:name="aNum"/></p>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

Then create a `@GetMapping` that will include `model.addAttribute("user", user);` however you plan to get/create the user.

By doing this, you're telling Spring to bind the values to the `user` bean.

You can remove the space after `aNum` and after the `<P>` tags too.  It sounds really perfectionist, but code formatted improperly is error-prone and harder for the next person to read.